# Multiple CAEmitterLayer sources

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics, caemitterlayer, caemittercell

I want to generate different CAEmitterCells from multiple points. So far my solution is to created multiple CAEmitterLayers, each with one cell, so that I can control them individually. The problem with this approach is setting the layers render mode to kCAEmitterLayerAdditive works only within each layer, so when particles emitted from different Layers overlap they don't blend making the problem very obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using SKEmitterNodes